# How can I resolve the "invalid ELF header" warning when trying to SSH and what does it mean?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm getting some kind of warning when checking my connection to github. Why is it happening and how can I resolve it?

```
$ ssh -TI ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
dlopen /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa failed: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa: invalid ELF header
Hi mediapop/Gnossem-Magazine! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You mistaken options `-i` and `-I` of OpenSSH.

From `man ssh`:

> -I pkcs11 - Specify the PKCS#11 shared library ssh should use to communicate with a PKCS#11 token providing the user's private RSA key.
>
> -i identity_file - Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.

After `-I` ssh expects shared library and tries to load your `id_rsa` as shared library, so it expects ELF header.

In this case you can omit `-i` because `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is default file.

Comment: OH, how very PEBKAC of me. :)

Comment: I can't believe I came here before reading the man page‍♂️
Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are not the only one and it happens from me from time to time, because in general I use a config file and totally forget the flags^^